# Sqlite library is not working

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am working on a Windows 8 Metro application.
When I use `[PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]`, it does need a library.

`Using Sqlite;`

But when I import this libray, the error remains.

Plz help me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS2012, main Menu go to TOOLS, Select Library Package Manager > Manager NuGet Package for Solution. Then click on Online  and write in Search Box "Sqlite-net" and Install it.

this will work fine.